# chef converge failed, but no error reported

Tags: chef-infra

I am seeing `chef` converge failed with no errors.

**Error Message :**

```
Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 21 resources updated in 14 seconds
```

Could somebody Please tell me where is it failing?

Comment: Please gist the full log, preferably at debug level (it will be very big).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer why chef-client is failing . I Had to change permissions on chef-server to update the chef-client.